# How to divide the date from JSON output?

Tags: iphone, json, date, nsdictionary

I am developing one application.In that i use the json.Json gives the output and that output is stored in one dictionary like

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];
NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
```

So my problem is how to separate the data from results.I want to print the only city name.so please tell me how to extract the data from dictionary.

Comment: What are the contents of `responseString`?

Comment: Try to accept answers for your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to see the response and by using `objectForKey:` (method in NSDictionary) you can find what ever you want. (pick data by their key).

Comment: At top label there is a dictionary suppose in most cases all the dictionaries present in an array by data:, so after getting this dictionary there is an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Check [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Use  `objectForKey:` to retrive the data. The key will be your tag value.